# Template Function Specialization - const

Tags: c++, templates

Why does template specialization C) work with base template A) but not with template B)?

A)

```
template<class t>
t* maxn( t*, int);
```

B)

```
template<class t>
const t* maxn(const t*, int);
```

C)

```
template<> const char** maxn<const char*>(const char*arr[], int);
```

Comment: I wonder if that has to do with what the const is being associated with? I'm no expert here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first, the parameter named `arr` is actually of type `const char**`. Now we will see what happens for each case.

##### Case A

Here we consider the following:

```
template<class t> t* maxn( t*, int);  //primary template 
template<> const char** maxn<const char*>(const char*arr[], int); //specialization
```

In the above, we've specialized the function template for when `t = const char*` which means `t*` will be `const char**` which matches with the parameter `const char*arr[]` is. So this works.

---

##### Case B

Here we consider the following:

```
template<class t> const t* maxn(const t*, int); //primary template
template<> const char** maxn<const char*>(const char*arr[], int); //specialization
```

In this case we are again specializing the function template for `t = const char*` but this time the first parameter of the primary template is `const t*` which for when `t = const char*`  will become `const t* = const char *const *` .

And since the parameter `const char*arr[]` is equivalent to `const char**` and **not** `const char *const *`, we get the mentioned error.

---

##### Solution

To solve this, use the following:

```
template<class t>const t* maxn(const t*, int);

//---------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv-------------------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv------------>works now
template<> const char*const* maxn<const char*>(const char*const* arr, int);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4edhTh6oM)